# API Documentation Manager and Browser for Windows

Tags: windows, macos

The other day i found about a cool utility : Dash – Snippet Manager, Documentation Browser

This utility is collection of documentation of popular frameworks.

http://kapeli.com/dash/

However this is avaialble for Mac OS X only. Is there some tool/utility available for Windows as well ?

P.S Must have utility for Mac boys....

Comment: I'm Dash's developer. I have no idea if a similar app is available for Windows, but I do plan on bringing Dash to Windows at some point. However, this might not happen too soon (around 6-12 months).

Comment: I've created a project inspired by Dash for browsing documentation, working with Windows and Linux. You can see see its [project page](https://github.com/jkozera/zeal/) at github, which contains a link to Windows binary. Apparently I'm not allowed to post self-promoting answers, hence a comment

Comment: Any plans of porting Dash to Windows have been cancelled. I gave it my best shot, but decided it's best to leave it to someone that knows what he's doing. The good news is that I'm collaborating with Zeal's developer (@jkozera) and we're exchanging docsets for the benefit of both Dash and Zeal users.

Comment: @bogdansrc thanks .. hope to see jkozera's awesome stuff soon :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey I've recently released [Velocity](http://velocity.silverlakesoftware.com) for Windows (a commercial product) that uses the docsets from Dash - [Meet Velocity for Windows](http://blog.kapeli.com/meet-velocity-for-windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know only Zeal but this one looks not so far advanced like Dash is. 
Anyways it can be usefull: **[Zealdocs.org](http://zealdocs.org/)**

Comment: You can also try https://velocity.silverlakesoftware.com/ it a paid application but you can use free with full functionality and for browser try devdocs.io (smartphone supported)